# django: How to let PermissionDenied exception display the reason?

Tags: django, django-views

I write a code like this in dispatch() of a view to constrain access to specific user:

```
if user.name != 'admin':
    raise PermissionDenied("you don't have access")
```

If the exception was raised, it just display on the redirected page of:

> 403 Forbidden

is it possible to let django display the error page with reason like:

```
403 Forbidden
you don't have access
```

Comment: Could you post complete error log ?

Comment: @dhana sorry the question was not clear, there is nothing wrong, I just want ask if I can show the exception description on the exception page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Django middleware with `HttpResponseForbidden`. It would look something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseForbidden

class ForbiddenMiddleware(object):
    """
        Don't give permissions for particular without admin
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
           return HttpResponseForbidden("403 Forbidden , you don't have access")
        return None
```

Note: The above middleware applies for all views.

If you want to restrict the check to a particular view, do this:

```
def my_view(request, ):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
      return HttpResponseForbidden("403 Forbidden , you don't have access")
    else:
        # your render
```

**Update 2020**

In Django 3.0, you have to import the `HttpReponseForbidden` class from `http`, like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
```